# Cols, colgroups and css ":hover" pseudoclass

Tags: css, xhtml, html-table, col

I'm trying to create a table to display an individual's BMI.

As a part of this, I'd like, on `:hover`, for the `<tr>` **and** `<col>` (or `<colgroup>`) to be highlighted also, in order for the intersection to be more apparent.

As the table will feature both metric and imperial measurements, the :hover doesn't have to stop at the cell (from any direction) and would, in fact, be a bonus if it extended from one axis to the other. I'm also using the XHTML 1.1 Strict doctype, if this makes a difference?

So... an example (the real table's... larger), but this should be representative:

```
<script>

tr:hover {background-color: #ffa; }

colgroup:hover,
col:hover {background-color: #ffa; }

</script>
```

...

```
<table>
    <col class="weight"></col><colgroup span="3"><col class="bmi"></col></colgroup>

    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>50kg</th>
        <th>55kg</th>
        <th>60kg</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>160cm</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>23</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>165cm</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>22</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>170cm</td>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>21</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Am I asking the impossible, do I need to go JQuery-wards?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Here's a pure CSS method using no JavaScript.

I used `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements to do the row and column highlighting. `z-index` keeps the highlighting below the `<td>`s in case you need to handle click events. `position: absolute` allows them to leave the confines of the `<td>`. `overflow: hidden` on the `<table>` hides the highlight overflow.

It wasn't necessary, but I also made it select just the row or column when you're in the headers. The `.row` and `.col` classes take care of this. If you wish the simplify, you can remove them.

This works in all modern browsers (and degrades gracefully on older browsers by doing nothing).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/rUhCa/

Output:

[image: HTML table with highlighted row and column]

CSS:

```css
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

td, th, .row, .col {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

td:hover::before,
.row:hover::before { 
    background-color: #ffa;
    content: '\00a0';  
    height: 100%;
    left: -5000px;
    position: absolute;  
    top: 0;
    width: 10000px;   
    z-index: -1;        
}

td:hover::after,
.col:hover::after { 
    background-color: #ffa;
    content: '\00a0';  
    height: 10000px;    
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;  
    top: -5000px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;        
}
```

HTML:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th class="col">50kg</th>
        <th class="col">55kg</th>
        <th class="col">60kg</th>
        <th class="col">65kg</th>
        <th class="col">70kg</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="row">160cm</th>
        <td>20</td><td>21</td><td>23</td><td>25</td><td>27</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="row">165cm</th>
        <td>18</td><td>20</td><td>22</td><td>24</td><td>26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="row">170cm</th>
        <td>17</td><td>19</td><td>21</td><td>23</td><td>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="row">175cm</th>
        <td>16</td><td>18</td><td>20</td><td>22</td><td>24</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: May I respond with a +1 and an acceptance? I played around with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements last night (when I remembered the question), but could quite get them to work as I wanted. Thanks! =)

Comment: The fix for firefox is not needed anymore.

Comment: You might be interested to know that there's a [css-tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/) that links to your answer here.

Comment: This works great in all the browsers I tested (IE9, IE11, FF, Chrome) - the FF fix seems to be no longer necessary :-)

Comment: You should ensure that overflow:visible is set on td!

Comment: this approach does not work if <td> has background color. Does anyone know what to do in such case?

Comment: Does not work if there is a sticky header because of overflow: hidden

Answer (score 8):

There is a very decent jQuery plugin I've come across [located here](http://p.sohei.org/stuff/jquery/tablehover/demo/demo.html) which does a very good job of this kind of thing with loads of examples.  Preferentially I'd use that.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice, though, to be able to use CSS as it should -in my imagination be able to- be used? =) I'll check out the JQuery, thanks for that!

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK CSS Hovers on `TR`'s aren't supported in IE anyway, so at best the TR part of that will only work in Firefox.

Never even seen a `:hover` work on a col/colgroup so not sure if that's possible...

Think you might be stuck with a Javascript implementation.

Theres an example [here](http://centricle.com/lab/dom/col/)  that works (rows & cols) in Firefox
but again its broken in IE... cols don't work.

Comment: That's definitely consistent with my experiences, if not quite the miracle I was hoping for... =)

Comment: Depends on the doctype and the version.  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> works in IE7 anyway.

Comment: The :hover state will not only work in Firefox, but every other major non-IE browser (Opera, Konqueror, Safari, et al).

Answer (score 3):

Live answer (https://jsfiddle.net/craig1123/d7105gLf/)

There are already CSS and JQuery answers; however, I have written a simple pure javascript answer.

I first find all the `col` and `td` tags, get the column index of each cell by doing `element.cellIndex`, and then add a CSS class with a background on `mouseenter` and removing it on `mouseleave`.

HTML

```
<table id='table'>
  <col />
  <col />
  <col />
  <col />
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Birthdate</th>
      <th>Preferred Hat Style</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Abraham Lincoln</td>
      <td>204</td>
      <td>February 12</td>
      <td>Stovepipe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Winston Churchill</td>
      <td>139</td>
      <td>November 30</td>
      <td>Homburg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rob Glazebrook</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>August 6</td>
      <td>Flat Cap</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font: 16px/1.5 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

table {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th {
  text-align: left;
}
table tr, table col {
  transition: all .3s;
}
table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 140, 203, 0.2);
}
table col.hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 140, 203, 0.2);
}
tr, col {
  transition: all .3s;
}
tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,140,203,.2);
}
col.hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,140,203,.2);
}
```

JS

```
const col = table.getElementsByTagName('col');
const td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

const columnEnter = (i) => col[i].classList.add('hover');
const columnLeave = (i) => col[i].classList.remove('hover');

for (const cell of td) {
    const index = cell.cellIndex;
    cell.addEventListener('mouseenter', columnEnter.bind(this, index));
    cell.addEventListener('mouseleave', columnLeave.bind(this, index));
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/craig1123/d7105gLf/)

Answer (score 2):

I came accross this neat way of doing it its from [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/) I also prepared a fiddle whilst messing around with it nothing fancy but u can get the idea its with the same code provided by that css-trick page

//The Html

```
<table>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

//The Js

```
$(function(){
    $("table").delegate('td','mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
        if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
          $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
          $("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).addClass("hover");
        }
        else {
          $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
          $("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).removeClass("hover");
        }
    });
})
```

[Check out the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Egli/dsujqo69/)

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @ThinkingStiff's pure CSS method, here's an approach with the same output based on `:has()` pseudo-classes (and without needing `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements). `:has()` support [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas()).

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/x37v/tf2a43k5/

HTML

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>50kg</th>
      <th>55kg</th>
      <th>60kg</th>
      <th>65kg</th>
      <th>70kg</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>160cm</th>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>27</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>165cm</th>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>26</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>170cm</th>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>175cm</th>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

/*  Row rules: Excluding the top row, highlight any row that the mouse is over */
table:has(tr:not(:nth-child(1)):hover) tr:hover,

/*  Column rules: Highlight the respective columns on td:hover and th:hover (omitting the first column) */
table:has(td:nth-child(2):hover, th:nth-child(2):hover) col:nth-child(2),
table:has(td:nth-child(3):hover, th:nth-child(3):hover) col:nth-child(3),
table:has(td:nth-child(4):hover, th:nth-child(4):hover) col:nth-child(4),
table:has(td:nth-child(5):hover, th:nth-child(5):hover) col:nth-child(5),
table:has(td:nth-child(6):hover, th:nth-child(6):hover) col:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: #ffa;
}
```