# How to Dynamically Set Table Column Background Color on Hover?

Tags: html, css, background, html-table, hover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cols, colgroups and css :hover psuedoclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848840/cols-colgroups-and-css-hover-psuedoclass)

How can I set the background color of an HTML table column when a cell (td) in that column is hovered over?

Comment: You're right. My question is a duplicate. I will edit this and link to your original question. Thank you!

Comment: It can be done with just CSS. I just answered it over on @DavidThomas question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/848840/918414

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can get away with a hover on table instead of hover on `td`: http://jsfiddle.net/DkN2R/

If your `td`s doesn't have spacing / margin you can get away with it.

Otherwise you would have to resort to javascript, because CSS cannot handle ancestor selectors. I heard some rumors about them maybe in the far far future being implemented, but that may take a while. The reason for this was performance if I recollect correctly.