# Color table columns from N onwards (td:nth-of-type)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-tables

I want to add a certain background color from a certain column onwards. Instead of having to use a css class for each column, i would rather prefer to do it otherwise if possible.

I will have a huge table with hundreds of rows and around 25 columns and I prefer to avoid unnecessary code.

Currently, I am using `td:nth-of-type` property to do it:

```css
.demo tr.selectedRow td:nth-of-type(9),
.demo tr.selectedRow td:nth-of-type(10),
.demo tr.selectedRow td:nth-of-type(11),
.demo tr.selectedRow td:nth-of-type(12),
.demo tr.selectedRow td:nth-of-type(13),
.demo tr.selectedRow td:nth-of-type(14),
.demo tr.selectedRow td:nth-of-type(15),
.demo tr.selectedRow td:nth-of-type(16) {
  background-color: #fff16b;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="demo">
  <tr>
    <td>not selected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectedRow">
    <td>not selected</td>
    <td>not selected</td>
    <td>not selected</td>
    <td>not selected</td>
    <td>not selected</td>
    <td>not selected</td>
    <td>not selected</td>
    <td>not selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>not selected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>not selected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>not selected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>not selected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>not selected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>not selected</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I was wondering if there's any way to reduce this even more.

[The documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) doesn't say much more...

Comment: Be aware that W3Schools is not *the* documentation - that would be http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/ This tester can really help. It looks like you want to select everything after 9 so use the code below

Select every TD except The First 8

```css
.demo tr.selectedRow td:nth-child(n+9) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="demo">
  <tr>
    <td>not selected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectedRow">
    <td>not selected</td>
    <td>not selected</td>
    <td>not selected</td>
    <td>not selected</td>
    <td>not selected</td>
    <td>not selected</td>
    <td>not selected</td>
    <td>not selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
    <td>selected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>not selected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>not selected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>not selected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>not selected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>not selected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>not selected</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good but, what if i don't want to fill the last 2 columns, for example? Would it be possible?

Comment: .demo tr.selectedRow td:nth-last-child(1), .demo tr.selectedRow td:nth-last-child(2) {
    color: red;   
} this will select the bottom 2

Comment: But there's no way to say, from column 4 to column 8 without having to deal also with columns 1-4 and 8-n, right?

Comment: @Steve: Sure there is, just chain two `:nth-child()`s together like so: `.demo tr.selectedRow td:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+8)` This selects `td`s that are in *both ranges only*, giving you *only* columns 4 to 8.

Comment: Keep in mind that `:nth-child()` and `:nth-of-type()` aren't always the same for `td` elements as you may have row-based `th` elements on each row to worry about. These will not affect `td:nth-child()` counts, but will affect `td:nth-of-type()` counts because they're different element types.

Answer (score 0):

If every column after the eight why don't you have a class for the first eight and nothing for the others. This would work if all the rest should be the same of course.

*This would work on IE even.*

#### Example using colgroup

```css
.colSpecial {
  background-color: #fee;
}

.colDefault {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #efe;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="colDefault" />
    <col class="colDefault" />
    <col class="colDefault" />
    <col class="colDefault" />
    <col class="colDefault" />
    <col class="colDefault" />
    <col class="colDefault" />
    <col class="colDefault" />
    <col class="colSpecial" />
    <col class="colSpecial" />
    <col class="colSpecial" />
    <col class="colSpecial" />
    <col class="colSpecial" />
    <col class="colSpecial" />
    <col class="colSpecial" />
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: As I said, i would prefer not to have add 900 classes in the final HTML :)  (9cols x 100 rows)

Comment: But surely yu should be able to put in on the column itself with the help of the cols element?

Comment: The idea is not bad, in fact, more simple than the previous one for static backgrounds, but it is much more difficult to make it work with the `:hover` event. [There are some tricks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11175979/1081396) using `:before ` but seems not the best solution...

Comment: I must have missed the `:hover` demand, where is that stated?

Comment: I didn't talk about it, but it is a disadvantage of using the colgroup.

Comment: Do you need unique hover action on each td or do you want the whole row to be changed? In the latter case you can use the `:hover` selector on the tr element only.

Comment: I need an hover action over various TDs over various rows at the same time. From column 8 for example to column 19. But don't worry, it is already done with the previous answer.