# CSS selector for all table columns greater than nth-of-type(2)?

Tags: css, css-selectors

My current CSS selects the 2nd column:

```
tr td:nth-of-type(2) {
  padding-left:20px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

How can I target all columns after the 2nd?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could use:

```
tr td:nth-of-type(2) ~ td
```

The  **[~ (general sibling selector)](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector)** will select all `<td>` sibling elements **after** the second one.

Note though that `nth-of-type` [**isn't supported in older versions of IE**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthoftype) (8 and before).

Alternatively, you could use `td:nth-child(n+3)` - again this isn't supported in IE8 and before, but if you wanted to use `nth-child` (*not just for this one case obviously*) and happen to be using a JavaScript library such as jQuery, there is always [**Selectivizr**](http://selectivizr.com/), which will make it (and various other selectors) work in IE6 through to IE8.

Comment: @HelloWorld If the rest of the world shared your attitude, it would be a happier place :D

Comment: I just wish IE11 also for Win7 than I can kick IE9 too :P

Answer (score 15):

this will work...

```
tr td:nth-of-type(n+3)
{
    padding-left:20px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

[similar question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476428/color-table-columns-from-n-onwards-tdnth-of-type)

Comment: This includes the second `<td>`, they want to select every `<td>` after the second.

Answer (score 4):

```
td + td + td {

}
```

Will match the third columns and all columns afterward. This is CSS2 and does not require the "nth-of-type" property - which is not supported in legacy browsers like the browser (IE7) I am using now!

Comment: it is expected that you format your html properly as in - all `<td>` tags are in the container and you are not mixing in other tags. If you are mixing tags use - `td ~ td ~ td` but I discourage the use of the selector as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just define a colgroup and apply the styling to that.