# Using CSS and Bootstrap 3 in order to highlight the currently hovered-on row and column of a html table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to be able to use **Bootstrap 3** or/and **plain css** in order to **highlight the currently hovered-on row and column of a html table**.

Is this possible without using custom javascript and **keeping the responsiveness** of Bootstrap tables?

Can anyone please provide advice and/or links?

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: couldn't you just add a `newClass` to the current table and add the `newClass:hover` in the css ?

Comment: @MAD4RA: thanks. I know about :hover but where do I put it in order for the current column to be "selected" and highlighted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `.table-hover` to enable a hover state on table rows

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  ...
</table
```

Create a parent div with class `.table-responsive` to responsiveness

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Solution with `:nth-child()` to identify `:hover` column number

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/kGz9E/

Reference: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a way to have the same behavior applied to the current column as well as the current row?

Comment: @balteo I don't think it is possible without using javascript. Because  CSS doesn't provide any option to idendify exact column :(. You can use some few amount scripting solution something like this http://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/

Comment: Umm. I did find something on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848840/cols-colgroups-and-css-hover-psuedoclass with its corresponding fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/rUhCa/ but it is not responsive at all and does not integrate with bootstrap...

Comment: Which leads me to think that a pure-css solution is possible.

Comment: @balteo do you have any IE requirement for it ?

Comment: @balteo Then I would suggest use `:nth-child()` to detect column number and declare a unique css for that column :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49042/discussion-between-bboymaanu-and-balteo)

Comment: @balteo please have a look updated answer hope that should be useful for you

Comment: @balteo use the logic which used in **demo** not exact code because the code quickly made one ;)

Comment: i thought table-responsive class must be used for table tag, but after read this then only know that i can put it to the parent div of the table, it solved the problem of extra one column if putting table-responsive and table-bordered in the table tag