# Internet Explorer table performance with hover

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hover, html-table

I have a table with a structure like this:

```
<tr>                 
  <td class="data">
    <input type="number" step="0.5" min="0" name="data" value="1" />
    <div class="increment-decrement">
      <a class="increment-button"></a>
      <a class="decrement-button"></a>
    /div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

64 row, 13 cell each. I have hover effect on every `<tr>`, that gives the row highlight and another hover on every `<td>` that sets the inner div's `display` property to `inline-block`. 
When I mouse over in Internet Explorer (even in IE11) the rows and cells hover effect lags like hell. In Chrome it is really smooth. If I remove the input fields the performance is okay, but I need those.

Comment: User full link for u will help u: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848840/cols-colgroups-and-css-hover-psuedoclass/11175979#11175979

Comment: Thanks, I will try it, but this could only solve the row and cell coloring part. I have `<div>`s inside the `<td>`s, that must be shown on hover.