# Column outline overriden by row highlight? (html table, css formatting)

Tags: css, html-table

I used a derivation of ThinkingStiff's answer to this question [cols, colgroups and css :hover psuedoclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848840/cols-colgroups-and-css-hover-psuedoclass/11175979#11175979) to create a table that outlines columns and highlights rows on hover. (Vertical column headers intentionally not outlined).

See below:

```css
table {
  overflow: hidden;
}
caption {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0px
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%
}
th, td {
    width: 100px;  
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
tr:hover {
  background-color: #FBFEFD;
}

td:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  outline: solid black 2px !important;
  left: 0;
  top: -5000px;
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<table class="ComparisonTable">
 <caption>Comparison Table</caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="CompTabProdCat">Category</th>
      <td>ProdCat1</td>
      <td>ProdCat2</td>
      <td>ProdCat3</td>
      <td>ProdCat4</td>
      <td>ProdCat5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="CompTabProdName">ProdName</th>
      <td>ProdName1</td>
      <td>ProdName2</td>
      <td>ProdName3</td>
      <td>ProdName4</td>
      <td>ProdName5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="CompTabProdRat">Rating</th>
      <td>ProdRating1</td>
      <td>ProdRating2</td>
      <td>ProdRating3</td>
      <td>ProdRating4</td>
      <td>ProdRating5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="CompTabProdPho">Photo</th>
      <td>ProdImage1</td>
      <td>ProdImage2</td>
      <td>ProdImage3</td>
      <td>ProdImage4</td>
      <td>ProdImage5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="CompTabProdSum">Summary</th>
      <td>ProdSum1</td>
      <td>ProdSum2</td>
      <td>ProdSum3</td>
      <td>ProdSum4</td>
      <td>ProdSum5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Does anyone know why the column outline disappears for the selected row? I thought the !important tag would maintain that outline, but apparently not. Any other workarounds available to maintain that outline?

Bonus question is why I'm losing the rightmost border (less stuck and less concerned with that question).

Thanks a ton; I appreciate it!

Comment: Why are you using position relative on your table cells?

Comment: Short answer is because doing so allowed the outline to work (minus the row highlight). When I remove the position-relative line, outline stops working entirely. Why that's the case.. I don't know. I'm awfully new at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After monkeying around a bit, I think I have a working solution for you.

```
table {
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: visible;
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 19px;
  position: relative;
}

caption {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 617px;
  z-index: 20;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%
}

th,
td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #FBFEFD;
}

td:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  outline: solid black 2px !important;
  left: 0;
  top: -5000px;
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100%;
  /*z-index: -1;*/
}
```

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/rntyt13u/2/

I can help you tweak it from here if more work is needed.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.. thanks! I'll probably change some of the caption stuff stylistically, but that's just based on preference, and this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a css only solution, but some brief javascript took care of it.

Used box-shadow to avoid shifting text (as border would do) or highlighting full cells (as outline would do).

```js
$('td').hover(function() {
    var t = parseInt($(this).index()) + 1;
    $('td:nth-child(' + t + ')').addClass('ct-col-highlighted');
},
function() {
    var t = parseInt($(this).index()) + 1;
    $('td:nth-child(' + t + ')').removeClass('ct-col-highlighted');
});
```

```css
.comparison-table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.comparison-table caption {
  padding: 15px
}

.comparison-table th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: auto; 
  height: 50px;
}

.comparison-table tr:hover {
  background-color: #FBFEFD;
}

.ct-col-highlighted {
 box-shadow: -2px 0px 0px 0px black, 3px 0px 0px 0px black;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='comparison-table'>
 <caption>Caption</caption>
 <tr>
  <th>H-A</th>
  <td>A1 </td>
  <td>A2</td>
  <td>A3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>H-B</th>
  <td>B1</td>
  <td>B2</td>
  <td>B3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>H-C</th>
  <td>C1</td>
  <td>C2</td>
  <td>C3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>H-D</th>
  <td>D1</td>
  <td>D2</td>
  <td>D3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```