# Unable to change css using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, handsontable

Inside of handsontable's _afterOnCellMouseOver function, I am trying to change the css color property for my column headers when i hover over them.

```js
_afterOnCellMouseOver(e, coords, td) {
    if (coords.row === -1 &&& this.hot) {
        let contElem = document.getElementById(`cont${varId}`);
        contElem.style.color = "purple";
    }
}
```

```css
div.hotColHeaderContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="${styles.hotColHeaderContainer}" id=cont${varId}> </div>
```

My div.hotColHeaderContainer is contained inside of a scss file and my div is made inside of a function that is used to generate my column header. varId is a variable that changes name depending on the variable name used in the column header. Is there any reason why I am unable to change the style from within _afterOnCellMouseOver? I am very new to javascript, handsontable and css.

Comment: you can do it without using js, using css hover property

Comment: why `<div class="${styles.hotColHeaderContainer}" id=cont${varId}> </div>` should work? that's not possible on pure html. Are you using any framework?

Comment: As @Rumesh said, indeed drop JS for Over behavior. Use a full CSS solution by using :hover selector https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848840/cols-colgroups-and-css-hover-psuedoclass

Comment: Is a javascript solution not possible at all? Hover works just fine, but I'm just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the css `hover` selector. Snippet below:

```css
div.hotColHeaderContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
}
div.hotColHeaderContainer:hover {
    color: purple
}
```

```html
<div class='hotColHeaderContainer'>Hello</div>
```