# Is there a way to apply CSS hover on the col element

Tags: css, html-table, hover

Is there a way to apply the **`:hover`** pseudo class on the **`col`** element in CSS? When I go to **DevTools**, I can indeed force a hover state on any `col` and DevTools will apply specified `:hover` style on it though. It seems like I cannot get through to my cols through my interface...

I have set a desired background color to those cols, but I wish to change their background color on hover.

**CSS:**

```
table colgroup col{
  background-color: #e6f2ff; /* applied correctly */
}

table colgroup col:hover{
  background-color: #ccccff; /* NOT applied */
}
```

Few details for informative purposes:

- My table cannot have `overflow: hidden` (sticky stuff reasons) so please don't recommend [Cols, colgroups and css ":hover" pseudoclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848840/cols-colgroups-and-css-hover-pseudoclass)
- `colgroup` inside my `table` comes before `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot`
- I've tried setting `pointer-events` to `none` for everything except for the `colgroup` and `col`, but to no avail.
- I would like to skip scripting to accomplish this (performance reasons).

Comment: Why don't you have a look at this CSS-tricks, might help [link](https://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/)

Comment: That resource is actually just another implementation of the resource I've linked as non-relatable. I cannot have overflow: hidden on the table due to some other reasons, hence using pseudo elements with extremely large dimensions is not viable. Another thing, such example is only possible on simple tables from what I've seen.

Comment: why include `colgroup` in the selector? It is not doing anything for you there.

Comment: for navigation purposes simply, it could be just col and col:hover, but it is more clear to someone reading that the col is part of the colgroup that is part of the table xy.